# on option item is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT:
I forgot http:// on the links. This is not my problem. I'll fix the question...

i have some options, like this:

```
<select class="mySelect">
    <option value="http://www.url1.com">Url 1</option> <!--Default displayed--->
    <option value="http://www.url2.com">Url 2</option>
    <option value="http://www.url3.com">Url 3</option>
</select>
```

To this i have a jquery listener, looks like this:

```
$('.mySelect').change(function(){
    window.location.replace($(this).val());
});
```

Since this just responds to a change made, i can't be redirected to "www.url1.com". What should i use? I only get suggestions for change on google.

EDIT 2: I've got a bunch of solutions on using a dummy as first option. I also got the other solution of using a button to read the selected option and then redirect, but that's not usable in the project i'm working on, even if these are really good solutions otherwise.

In this case, i want it to listen for usage, even if the change is made to itself, like i'm selecting the first option (that's selected by default) i want it to do something with it - In the case above a redirect. I'll leave it open if someone have a good solution to this problem.

Comment: you can just put a dummy option as the first option like "select url.."

Comment: Yes, that's an option. But not in the actual case i'm working on. :)

Answer (score 8):

Try putting in an empty valued first option:

```
<select class="mySelect">
    <option value="">Please select...</option>
    <option value="http://www.url1.com">Url 1</option>
    <option value="http://www.url2.com">Url 2</option>
    <option value="http://www.url3.com">Url 3</option>
</select>
```

You can then amend your jQuery to make sure there is a value before redirecting:

```
$('.mySelect').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value != "") {
       window.location.replace(value);
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XjXWS/)

Note also that `http://` (or whichever protocol you're using) is required on the link values.

---

**Updated**

If you would prefer to not have the dummy option, you would need to change the logic to work on button click:

```
<select class="mySelect">
    <option value="http://www.url1.com">Url 1</option>
    <option value="http://www.url2.com">Url 2</option>
    <option value="http://www.url3.com">Url 3</option>
</select>
<button id="redirect">Go</button>
```

```js
$("#redirect").click(function() {
    window.location.replace($(".mySelect").val());
});
```

Comment: in this case i don't want any dummies. otherwise that would be the best thing, yes!

Comment: In that case it's not possible to do what you want `onchange` as it would be impossible to select the first URL. The alternative is to have a button and redirect to the selected URL when the button is clicked.

Comment: @gubbfett see my update for how to do what I mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: Also a great solution, but not in this case. //Most annoying guy on earth? ;)

Comment: Well, since the case is not exactly like the above i need it to trigger when it's changed/used, even if it "changes" to itself.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible - `change` is not fired when the current option is chosen. Your only alternatives are the two I've outlined in my answer.

Comment: Yea, i'm starting to believe it's quite screwed. I started out trying to do like $('.mySelect').click and then have a bunch of statements here, but the click() does not work at all on <select>. At least not in chrome on mac os.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `http://` also

```
window.location.replace("http://"+$(this).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

One option can be that you change the first option like

```
    <select class="mySelect">
    <option value="select">Select URL</option> <!--Default displayed--->
    <option value="www.url1.com">Url 1</option> 
    <option value="www.url2.com">Url 2</option>
    <option value="www.url3.com">Url 3</option>
    </select>
```

or you can use click jquery event for combo box .

Comment: yea, i'm trying do do something like case 2. But "click()" is not triggered on comboboxes, at least not in chrome on mac os.

Answer (score -1):

```
<form>
<select class="mySelect">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
    <option value="www.url1.com">Url 1</option> 
    <option value="www.url2.com">Url 2</option>
    <option value="www.url3.com">Url 3</option>
</select>
</form>​

$(".mySelect").change( function() {
var n = $(this).val();
if(n != "") {
window.location.assign("http://"+n);
}
});​
```

Comment: in this case i don't want any dummies. otherwise that would be the best thing, yes!